# Is there an equivalent of Swift's guard statement in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, swift, if-statement

I'm starting to develop web apps but I come from the iOS world.
I was wondering if there was an equivalent of Swift's `guard` statement in JavaScript?
I love return early pattern.

For those who may not know, `guard` statement is a "return early if statement", here is a very basic example:

```
myCondition = trueOrFalse()
guard myCondition
   else {print("myCondition is false")
         return}
print("myCondition is true")
```

Comment: What makes it so special? Cant see how it's different from `if(! myCondition) { ... }`

Comment: Yeah, just use an `if`. I mean, what exactly do you want the `guard` keyword to do in `JavaScript`?

Comment: you're missing the most useful part of `guard`, which is that the syntax `guard let foo = bar else { ... }` declares `foo` to the enclosing scope

Comment: the alternative `if let foo = bar { }` only declares `foo` _inside_ the scope of the `if` block.

Comment: @Alnitak Well, just use `var` instead of `let` (in JS).

Comment: @Cristy As it happens, in Swift I actually tend to use `if` for typical guard use cases, _unless_ I specifically want the side effect of adding the declared variable to the current scope.

Comment: Yes, but in `JavaScript` simply using `var` instead of `let` would declare the variable for the enclosing **function scope**.

Comment: I think that the main benefit is that `guard` **forces** you to return. So when you read `guard`, you know that the branch inside is **guaranteed** to return early. It helps when reading code!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When inside a function you can **return early**. No need for an actual `guard`, you can use an `if` instead.

```
f () {
  myCondition = trueOrFalse()

  // Make sure `myCondition` is `true`
  if (!myCondition) return console.log("myCondition is false");

  console.log("myCondition is true")
}
```

PS: I `return` the log statement just to keep it on one line. `console.log` simply returns `undefined`, so your function will return `undefined`. You can split that statement on multiple lines if you think it looks better that way, or want your `function` return type to always the same as that might help with optimization (eg: always return an integer, so instead of `undefined` you could return `0`).

Comment: The powerful thing about Swift's `guard` is it lets you declare variables if the condition succeeds: `guard let name = something?.name else { return }`. Also the `else` must exit the scope or will not compile so its truly an enforced guard at compile time.